# Error php and mysql - unexpected T_IS_EQUAL

Tags: php, sql

The code is :

```
<?php

require_once('connection.php');

// Check $username and $password 
/*
if(empty($_POST['username']))
{
    echo "UserName/Password is empty!";
    return false;
}
if(empty($_POST['password']))
{
    echo "Password is empty!";
    return false;
}
*/

// Define $username and $password 
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=md5($_POST['pass']);

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$username1 = stripslashes($username);
$password2 = stripslashes($password);
$username3 = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password4 = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $WebsiteUsers WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if( mysql_num_rows($result) ==1){ //get num of rows
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($password4) == $row['password']
    {
        session_register("username");
        session_register("password"); 
        echo "Login Successful";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        return false;
    }
}
else{
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    return false;
}

?>
```

Error keeps saying:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL in /home/u771046626/public_html/IP/check-user.php on line 36

I've had a look, and cannot find my mistake so I am hoping that people on here can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the parens around the condition...

Change

```
if ($password4) == $row['password']
```

to

```
if ($password4 == $row['password'])
```

Comment: Doing as advised i get this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL in /home/u771046626/public_html/IP/check-user.php on line 36

Comment: Very odd... I just tested the code with the above change and receive no such error... and if I revert I DO get the error... is your web server caching the PHP?

Comment: im not sure i have tried numerous times and just get tat error

Comment: i am now getting Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u771046626/public_html/IP/check-user2.php on line 33 Wrong Username or Password

Comment: from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php   Return Values ¶

For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.   -- is the table name "WebsiteUsers"?  you currently have it as a variable  $WebsiteUsers which if empty will definitely cause an error and this "False" to be returned...

Comment: sorry could you try explaining that please

Comment: Sure... $result is most likely false, indicating an error with the query...  your code states $sql="SELECT * FROM $WebsiteUsers WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";  so the question is should it be $sql="SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";   in your current code, you're using $Websiteusers which is a variable which does not appear to be set, if the table is actually named WebsiteUsers then just remove the $ and try again ;-)

Comment: ive now changed code and still get: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u771046626/public_html/IP/check-user2.php on line 33 Wrong Username or Password, the code is 
$sql="SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

Comment: try echoing $sql and running directly on the database and see what you get...  depending upon the platform, the table / column names may be case sensitive  also look @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: it wont echo, still error: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u771046626/public_html/IP/check-user2.php on line 33 Wrong Username or Password

Comment: uh... I just noticed... I don't see mysql_connect anywhere, you'd need to do that first, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php  and in your query, I'd use $username3 and $password4

Comment: i have require_once('connection.php'); where the connection is stored

Comment: look @  php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and add error output after the mysql_query line, you'll need to know the connection variable, which is presumably in connection.php... paste connection.php if possible (replacing passwords with "xxx" of course)

Comment: do you have an email address i can contact you on and send you the files so you can see?

Comment: try dbinns66 at yahoo dot com

Answer (score 1):

On line 35, you have:

```
    if ($password4) == $row['password']
```

Should be:

```
    if ($password4 == $row['password'])
```

Comment: Hi, doing as you advised i got this error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL in /home/u771046626/public_html/IP/check-user.php on line 36

Comment: @LeslieBraham No, that was the only parse error so if you fix that, that is not the message you will get.

Answer (score 0):

On line 36 you should wrap your `if` in parentheses
e.g.

if ( $password4 == $row['password'] )
{
.
.
.

Comment: doing as advised  i have changed the code to look like: if( mysql_num_rows($result) ==1){ //get num of rows
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 if ($password4 == $row['password'])
 {
        session_register("username");
        session_register("password"); 
        echo "Login Successful";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        return false;
    }
}
else{
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    return false;
}
still get  error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL in /home/u771046626/public_html/IP/check-user.php on line 36